# What does it mean by RESISTORAXIAL-0.3 in EAGLE Sparkfun resistor library?

Tags: eaglecad

This may be a childish question but I don't know what does it mean by `RESISTORAXIAL-0.3` in EAGLE Sparkfun resistor library. Is it some kind of measurement? I am new in EAGLE as well as PCB designing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would expect that RESISTORAXIAL-0.3 refers to a footprint (PC Board pattern) for an axial leaded resistor, with mounting holes 0.3" apart.

An axial leaded resistor is the common through-hole type.  0.3" lead spacing would probably be for a 1/8 watt resistor.  If I recall correctly, I usually used 0.4" lead spacing for 1/4 watt resistors.

Comment: You can easily confirm that by simple inspection of the actual footprint pattern for the part.